# Selecting rows based on a checks on muitiple columns of a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following dataframe

```
ID Names Marks1 Marks2 Marks3
1  A     50     102    87
2  B     54     75     83
3  C     5      175    43
4  D     35     75     80
5  E     87     75     B
6  F     93     75     83
```

I have a list of columns `val colsForCheck = List(Marks1, Marks2, Marks3)`

And checks such as

- `50 <= Marks <= 100`
- Marks should contain only numbers

I need to apply the checks on the dataframe for the columns mentioned in the list and create a new dataframe with all rows that failed the check. In this case the new dataframe will be

```
ID Names Marks1 Marks2 Marks3
1  A     50     102    87
3  C     5      175    43
4  D     35     75     80
5  E     87     75     B
```

Comment: and you tried what? where is the Scala code so far? I mean, it's basically just using `filter` and `select`, isn't it? OR just good old SQL?

Comment: @UninformedUser, I have it at a direct filter based on the required columns one by one. How do I modify the filter that the conditions are put on the all columns mentioned on the list automatically ?

Comment: I have added solution, Please check & upvote or accept if it helps .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---+-----+------+------+------+
|id |names|marks1|marks2|marks3|
+---+-----+------+------+------+
|1  |A    |50    |102   |87    |
|2  |B    |54    |75    |83    |
|3  |C    |5     | 175  |43    |
|4  |D    |35    |75    |80    |
|5  |E    |87    |75    |B     |
|6  |F    |93    |75    |83    |
+---+-----+------+------+------+
```

**Filter Condition**

```
scala> val colsForCheck = Seq("marks1","marks2","marks3")
.map(c => !(
    col(c).cast("int").isNotNull && 
    col(c) >= 50 && col(c) <= 100)
)
.reduce(_ || _)
```

**Output**

```
scala> df.filter(colsForCheck).show(false)
+---+-----+------+------+------+
|id |names|marks1|marks2|marks3|
+---+-----+------+------+------+
|1  |A    |50    |102   |87    |
|3  |C    |5     | 175  |43    |
|4  |D    |35    |75    |80    |
|5  |E    |87    |75    |B     |
+---+-----+------+------+------+
```